# allow users to view only some tabs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new to jenkins and facing 2 issues.

1. Trying to restric some users to view only specific tabs. For example 
   if we have All, Dev1, Dev2 and Dev3 tabs I want a specific user to access only Dev1 and Dev2 
   tabs and they should not be seeing All and Dev3 tab. Is this possible in Jenkins
2. What ever jobs I add to Dev1, it is showing in All tabs as well. Can we restrict a job to appear only in Dev1 tab. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start by reading the [standard security setup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup) page to understand how to enable authentication.

For authorization controls the [matrix based authorization](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) is pretty good, but the [Role strategy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) offers more detailed user controls.